# ActiveRecord: Avoid inconsistency in has_many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, locking

Assume we have an usual M-M relationship between two tables, like:

**users**---< **users_tags** >--- **tags**.

In this post I'm only concerned about the relation user_tags, tags: I'd like to avoid that linked tags can be deleted. Only tags which aren't referenced should be destroyable.

The stupid way to do this would be:

```
class Tag
  def before_destroy  
    unless self.user_tags.empty?
      raise "error"
    end
  end
end
```

But I think there's a potential race condition, between the check user_tags.empty? and the actual delete.

The second approach could be to lock the whole **user_tags** table before checking if there are any references left.

And the third way I can think of would involve changes to the code which creates the actual reference:

**Add a reference into users_tags:**

1. Fetch the Tag
2. Lock it (to avoid concurrent destruction)
3. Create reference in users_tag
4. Commit

**The before_destroy handler then could:**

1. self.lock!
2. Check if there are any references
3. destroy self
4. Commit

Are there any better ways to do this? Which one is reliable / the best? I personally tend to the second one as it only needs logic in the before_destroy controller, but with the cost of having the whole table locked.

**Edit 1:**

While experimenting around with *LOCK TABLE* I realized that they are playing against my transactions. When using innodb you can either use transactions (and their locking features) or use LOCK/UNLOCK table, a mix of both worlds makes matters much much worse (LOCK/UNLOCK causes implicit commits, I missed that warning in the doc). But this just for the protocol.

(**Edit 2 (a few weeks later):** I fought with that issue again. So I want to stress again **Do not use LOCK TABLE**)

I'm right now tending to use a **SHARE LOCK** on the parent object (tag in the example)) when adding children, and a **FOR UPDATE** lock for deletions. But I'm still wondering if thats the way it's meant to be (Lock a Rang in the child table for a update in the parent table).

Btw. I also realise that this question is now completely independent of rails :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that would avoid locking and checking would be to simply create foreign keys. Attempting to delete something that is referenced in another table would create a SQL error.

Other than that, you're going to have to do a whole lot of paranoid checking to make sure you're not nuking out any required tags.

An alternative is to approach the problem from a different angle. For example, as a single transaction wipe out any unused tags. For example:

```
DELETE FROM tags WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(tag_id) FROM users_tags)
```

This has the disadvantage of not performing the before_destroy type behaviors on the model level, but that may not be an issue for you.

Comment: Thats correct, just using innodbs own referential integrity system  would make such things much easier. The rails way is to use the rails helpers instead of defining everything twice, not sure if thats really the best way.

I like you're approach with the subquery in the delete statement, I suspected that there's something like that. That statement is atomic, right?

Comment: That statement is atomic, but that is also a way of saying it will lock the table until it completes. For a large set of data this will cause LOCK FAILED timeouts for anyone trying to insert new rows into tags. So long as the DELETE statement can complete in a reasonable amount of time, it will work fine. Otherwise you'll have to get more creative.